# Parse CloudWatch Insights Logs

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am trying the parse some cloudwatch logs to build visual (pie chart, bar chart) representations. My log data is in JSON format and looks like below:

```
{
    "feature": "Feature 1",
    "container": "TestContainer",
    "user": {
        "mail": "email@gmail.com",
        "org": "temp_org",
        "external": true
    }
}

{
    "feature": "Feature 2",
    "container": "TestContainer1",
    "user": {
        "mail": "email1@gmail.com",
        "org": "temp1_org",
        "external": true
    }
}
```

I want to filter based on `feature`, `container`, `user` etc. For ex: how many request for "Feature 1".

Below is my CloudWatch log insights query:

```
fields @timestamp, @message, feature, container, user
| filter feature = "Feature 1"
| stats count(*) as Number_of_Request by feature
```

This query is giving me correct (filtered) results but it is not generating correct plot. Probably because the outcome is just one number not a time series. How do I aggregate it with the total number of requests so that it generate correct plots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no need to add filter. Below works fine:

```
fields @timestamp, @message, feature, container, user
| stats count(*) as Number_of_Request by feature
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).